# What to use instead of Jinput in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla-1.5, jinput

I have the following code:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgSystemTemplateSwitcher extends JPlugin
    {
        function onAfterInitialise()
            {
                $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                $session = JFactory::getSession();
                $template = $input->getCmd( 'template', '' );
                if ( $template !== '' ) {
                $session->set( 'templateChanged', $template );
                }
                if ( $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' )!== '' ) {
                $input->set( 'template', $session->get( 'templateChanged', '' ) );
                }
            }
    }
```

This code is used as plugin to change the template for the current user. They click a link which contains the `GET` parameter `template=mytemplate` and the template is saved into user session and gets displayed.

I changed:

```
$template = $input->getCmd( 'template', '' );
```

to

```
$template = JRequest::getVar('template');
```

But I have a Joomla 1.5 site which doesn't support the following:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

I got an error when try to set `$input->set()`.

Anyone can help me to port this code to 1.5 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set something on Joomla 1.5, you will need to use `setVar`, like so:

```
$template = JRequest::getVar('template');
JRequest::setVar('template', $template);
```

---

> **Disclaimer:**
>
> Joomla 1.5 is extremely old and is not officially supported anymore. You will also find people on here less willing to support you. Please consider migrating your website to the latest version of Joomla, mainly for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, no errors...but plugin not propertly working :(
I know that joomla upgrading is very difficult..

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have Joomla 1.5, nor do I wish to put it on my localhost. The best thing you can do is read through the Joomla documentation and other tutorials online. This is the issue with older versions of Joomla, people have to go to greater end to help

Comment: Ah, cookies cache problem: I clear cookies (two times!) and now this code works properly.
I will try to update to newest version also.
Thanks a lot!